# Should I try to reach the recommended credit limit utilization percentage in the 3 days given between due date and reporting?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

I have started with my first credit card account in May, it is a Quicksilver One from Capital One. I am using this to try to up my credit score overall in hopes of raising it enough to buy a house in the coming months/years.

From everything I have heard and read I should try to get a credit line utilization percentage anywhere from about 30%-40%. The issue I currently have is that Capital One's due date for payments is the 2nd of each month, and from what I can tell they report the usage statistics to the credit bureaus on the 5th of the month.

**Should I try to reach the recommended credit limit utilization percentage in the 3 days given between due date and reporting?**

Comment: You want your utilization to be UNDEr 30%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

On an ongoing basis your utilization means very little.  When you want to get a large loan, like a mortgage or maybe a car loan, you may want to take a look at your utilization and make sure it's not too high.  There is no utilization history and your utilization history is not considered in your credit score.

Generally speaking, regardless of the date the information is actually transmitted to the credit bureaus, the numbers reported are derived from your statement balance.

Utilization is WAY over scrutinized on sites like this and other credit-focused forums.  You shouldn't be maxing your card out every month, but even if you do it doesn't mean anything if you're not currently shopping for a new credit instrument.  As long as you get that ratio straightened out before you want a new credit instrument utilization should not be a concern.

If you are maxing your card and paying it to zero, wait a few months to establish some history then call your bank and ask for a line increase.

Comment: From Bankrate - "It is difficult, but possible, to get a mortgage with a credit score under 620." - I agree with you, the day to day, month to month is noise. A few months before thinking about looking for a home, see your score. If 740+, just go househunting. Otherwise, understand how many, if any, points can be gained from adjusting utilization.

Answer (score -3):

This recommendation is based on my knowledge/experience. Your cc utilization rate should be less than 30%. Your balance on the statement closing date, which is 3 - 5 days after your payment due date, is the balance reported to credit bureaus. You can call your credit card provider and obtain your statement closing date. Your credit score is affected by your cc utilization. I've noticed that my score increases around 15 - 20 points when my cc utilization is less than 20%. When accessing your credit report online, the cc utilization % will display and is a factor. So if your payment is due on the 14th, your statement closing date may be the 17th. I would recommend ensure that your balance is less than 30% of the credit line for up to 5 days after your payment due date. Also factor in the interest that will be added to your balance on the closing date. If your cc utilization % is down to 30% on your payment due date, once interest is added it will increase slightly over 30%.